# Accessing elements in 2D array that is an array of an array (variant)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vbscript

I'm new to vbscript, and I'm trying to figure out how to work with 2D arrays. From my research there are two ways of having a 2D array, one is a 2D array declared like :

```
Dim matrix(10, 10)
```

The problem with this type of 2D array however is that I cannot dynamically resize the array efficiently. So, I decided to have a 2D array that is essentially a 1D array of variants that are arrays. My code to populate the 2D array is below :

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\johnk\Desktop\test.xlsx")

intRow = 1
intCol = 1
ReDim matrix(10) 'two dimensional array; 

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    ReDim cols(10) 'columns to be inserted for each row
    Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow, intCol).Value = ""
        if UBound(cols) < intCol Then
            ReDim Preserve cols(intCol * 2)
        End If
        cols(intCol) = objExcel.Cells(intRow, intCol).Value
        obj1.Write(cols(intCol))
        intCol = intCol + 1
    Loop
    intCol = 1
    matrix(intRow) = cols
    obj1.Write(vbCrLf)
    if UBound(matrix) < intRow Then
        ReDim Preserve rows(intRow * 2)
    End If
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop
obj1.Write(vbCrLf)
obj1.Write(matrix(0)(0))
```

In this code I'm simply reading from an excel spreadsheet and inputting them into the matrix variable. However, when I try to access it :

```
obj1.Write(matrix(0)(0))
```

I get a type mismatch. I cannot loop through the array either :

```
For i = LBound(matrix) To UBound(matrix)
    For j = LBound(matrix(i)) To UBound(matrix(i))
        obj1.Write(matrix(i)(j))
    Next
    obj1.Write(vbCrLf)
Next
```

as I get a type mismatch on the inner loop. Am I declaring or populating the array incorrectly? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You start with `intRow = 1`, `ReDim matrix(10)` returns 1d aray with 11 elements (since arrays are zero-based by default), then you put the first row `matrix(intRow) = cols` into `matrix` array by index 1, and array element at index 0 left empty. Later you start from `For i = LBound(matrix) ...` which actually 0, thus `matrix(0)` returns `Empty`.

Comment: @omegastripes Ah such a stupid mistake. I fixed this, but LBound(matrix(i)) in the inner loop still returns a type mismatch. Am I accessing it incorrectly?

Comment: Also just to make the things clear, you are working with nested arrays, not 2D array.

Comment: How did you fix that?

Comment: I modified the two lines populating the arrays : cols(intCol) -> cols(intCol - 1), matrix(intRow) = cols -> matrix(intRow - 1) = cols       Edit : I am able to access matrix(0)(0) and it returns the correct value.

Comment: Why do you use `* 2` in `ReDim Preserve` statements? Should it be just `+ 1`?

Comment: I didn't want to resize the array every loop. I thought it would be more efficient if I doubled the size every time the size was not enough. However just in case I tried doing  +1 and I still get a type mismatch on the inner loop.

Comment: I opted to just loop through the first column and the first row to get the max and resize the array that way. That fixed the mismatch issue.

Comment: Please write an answer for your question, it may help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was causing the error. I was dynamically resizing the nested array which was causing UBound and LBound to cause mismatch errors because the arrays never had values up to the point in which it was resized.

For vbscript it seems like it's important that you know exactly how large your array must be and make sure your array is completely full up to the size number you specified, otherwise LBound and UBound will cause mismatch errors when you try to run it.